# Compile standalone assembly

Tags: remix, assembly

The solidity wiki explains that standalone assembly is [also](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/assembly.html#standalone-assembly) possible. However, I cannot compile it. For example:

```
{
  mstore(0x40, 0x60) // store the "free memory pointer"
  // function dispatcher
  switch div(calldataload(0), exp(2, 226))
  case 0xb3de648b {
    let r := f(calldataload(4))
    let ret := $allocate(0x20)
    mstore(ret, r)
    return(ret, 0x20)
  }
  default { revert(0, 0) }
  // memory allocator
  function $allocate(size) -> pos {
    pos := mload(0x40)
    mstore(0x40, add(pos, size))
  }
  // the contract function
  function f(x) -> y {
    y := 1
    for { let i := 0 } lt(i, x) { i := add(i, 1) } {
      y := mul(2, y)
    }
  }
}
```

(Taken from solidity docs).

How do I compile this? I'm pretty sure I have to add some flag in solc. Is it possible to compile this in remix?

Comment: How did you compile your program? What error did you get? Did you try compiling from the command using `solc`?

Comment: I would like to directly compile this in remix.

Comment: That syntax doesn't appear to be supported by remix I'd suggest to create an issue in github for remix developers to consider adding this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1472) GitHub the following question was asked regarding the status of standalone assembly:

> Is this already implemented? It shows up in the documentation but I
>   can see no other evidence of it being implemented:
>   http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/assembly.html?highlight=assembly#standalone-assembly

Response to this by the contributor was

> No, this is still work in progress. There is a note about it in the
>   documentation, but not too visible, I have to admit.

This is the only evidence that I have got which is related to the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my EVM assembler :)

It's extremely simple and compatible with `solc --asm` format

I'm currently using it in production without any issues, my current workflow is to use `solc` to output ABI files and substitute `bin` outputs with `solcasm` output

https://github.com/RafaelSalguero/evm-assembler